# Why is my Keras model predicting trend but not scale?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm making a model to predict a the irradiance value on a solar field. The thing is that my model, despite being very simple (added code below), performs very well. The problem is that for any reason, it predicts a different scale, giving almos always lower values but in the same trend. I have appended the plot which compares both outputs and real data, in train and test set. Also linked the dataset.

Some details: The model has a total of 24 columns which correspond to 24 pyranometers which are the ones that gives information about the sun. The model has just been trained with the first one for simplicity, therefore with more data we can achieve better performance. Also, I'm processing my data to have a 15 steps back in time and a predict window of 20 steps forward.

```
input = Input((LAG,1)) # LAG is the number of steps I take backward
hidden = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(input)
output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden)

model = Model(input, output)
```

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qftRf_iIi_frxB82RMMpwy8SV4VPlNPI/view?usp=sharing)

[Model output vs real in train set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKerX.png)

[Model output vs real in test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNBHy.png)

Comment: Are you sure it performs very well? It could just predict using the last value. Have you used a benchmark, naive method? It might just be a bad model and it extrapolates correspondingly badly

Comment: Using as a naive method changing the predict window to 1, instead of 20 (I said originally 10 but was a mistake) gives same result